# DOM Update slow in chrome than firefox looks like chrome has some rendering issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, dom

I have written a code which dumps large no of node in DOM . When i load it in **firefox** it renders in *2-3 secs* but in **chrome (ver:33)** it freezes the UI and rendering takes *long time(8-10 sec)* .

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total * 100;
                $("#fetchProgress").attr("value", percentComplete);
            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/GetSomething",
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
        ///process and dump to DOM//
        var fileLines = data.split('\n');
        var htmlString = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < fileLines.length; i++) {
            htmlString += '<span>' + (i + 1) + '. ' + fileLines[i]+</span>;
            if ((i % 1000) == 0) {
                $("#textPlace").append(htmlString);
                htmlString = '';
            }
        }
        fileLines = null;
        $("#textPlace").append(htmlString);
    }
});
```

I learned from internet that chrome has some rendering bugs and tried hacks from this URL.
    "[Chrome Bug - window.scroll method intercepts DOM Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924234/chrome-bug-updated-dom-not-rendering)"
 It started to work but now again it is not working .Please suggest something .
 Any help is appreciated . Tank size Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: you could format the file on the server and then append the string only one  time

Comment: Try closing the span tag (eg: `... + fileLines[i] + '</span>';`. This reduced re-rendering times considerably for my simple test-case. Probably because chrome didn't need to fix broken html.

Comment: @Yoshi: also tried that closing </span> , but no impovement yet.

Comment: A very minor change: move `$("#textPlace")` outside the `for()`, that way it doesn't have to find the element over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code, you have an array which you want to tie together with spans. You can remove the `for()` from your code (and the modulus in it(=slow) ), saving a lot of time:

```
htmlString = '<span>'+ fileLines.join("</span><span>") +'</span>';
```

That will not display the `i` number, but you could switch to `li`'s and use the numbers instead of bullets.

---

This might work too:

```
var fileLines = '<span>'+ data.replace('\n', '</span><span>') +'</span>';
```

This is a litte more messy (this could end in `</span><span></span>`, you need to trim `\n`'s to fix that (easy to do)), but it doesnt have to turn it into an array, which should speed things up

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion but anyway we have to tear and update large no of nodes into DOM. I also tried DOMFragement which didn't help. To see how much time it takes to generates that many node, i used **Mutation Observers** , but still chrome  take thrice the time taken than firefox to update the view.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can avoid the `append` to html under this function

```
            if ((i % 1000) == 0) {
                $("#textPlace").append(htmlString);
                htmlString = '';
            }
```

and only have one `append` at the very end of your code.  You want to limit the DOM manipulation - it affects the browser performance by triggering multiple browser reflow.

[Google Dev: Speeding up JavaScript: Working with the DOM](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/javascript-dom)

Taken out from the link above, you can work with something like this instead

```
var anchor, fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.innerHTML = 'test';
    fragment.appendChild(anchor);
  }
  element.appendChild(fragment);
```